# Returning a const reference in C++

Tags: c++

In the following code, _myFoo is a const reference to an object of type Foo.

```
struct Foo
{
};

const Foo& _myFoo();

const Foo& GetMyFoo()
{
    return _myFoo;
}
```

When I try to compile it, I get the following error:

```
error: invalid initialization of reference of type 'const Foo&' 
from expression of type 'const Foo& (*)()'
```

What am I doing wrong? Is there some way of returning _myFoo via a function call?

Comment: You forgot the parentheses when invoking `_myFoo`

Comment: `_myFoo` is a function just like `GetMyFoo`, and uses a reserved identifier.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`_myFoo` is not a variable, it's a function returning a `const Foo&` and that takes no parameters. Either change the declaration of _myFoo (and possibly put it inside struct Foo), or do return _myFoo(); and give `_myFoo` a definition.

Note though that if myFoo is indeed supposed to be a function, you should not prefix it with an underscore as I believe function names beginning with underscores are reserved.

Comment: It's not particularly function names, but global names. Functions inside a class or declared in a function are "fine" having a leading underscore, "fine" being that it's not a particularly *popular* style.

Comment: Doh! Apologies for the beginner question. Thanks for the help.